# What benefits do I lose by not merging release branches back to Trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

TLDR; My team's SVN branching strategy does not commit back to a trunk. This feels like an anti-pattern, I cannot instantly explain why. Is this a problem, and are those problems big enough to push for change?

Details-

My team's agreed-upon branching strategy is to create monthly release branches. Releases are handled by handing off a .ear file to another team to deploy - Not pointing them to our SVN Repository.

We keep a tag of the last commit before going to production of each branch, for later use. We build into a dev environment daily to catch breaking builds.

But when we create a branch for the next release, we branch from the existing release branch - And never commit back to or interact with Trunk. Any post-branch changes to the branched-from release are merged up until the prior release is finalized.

```
Trunk
|\
| April
|      \
|       May
.          \
.           June...
.
.
```

We've had issues with project branches, which are merged into the release they are anticipated to roll out in.

We do not use feature branches, so rolling back or removing changes from a release is a nuisance, since every release branch is both the dev and bug fix branch.

Other than these, are there fundamental SVN capabilities impacted by this branching strategy, ill effect on the repository, or other risks?

Comment: why are you branching at all? you could save the work and just develop on trunk. What are you doing on trunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, I could imagine that 'rolling back or removing changes from a release is a nuisance', but still feasible.

You will lose precious time when you hire new new developers with this SVN setup.  They will have a harder time learning, contributing, and troubleshooting to this repository.  In the same way that its important to have readable code, its important to have a readable repository.

If your team runs into problems with repository, it will be harder to seek outside advice from books, websites, and other people.

If you want to incorporate any kind of 3rd party software to your repository, it may be difficult since the SVN convention of using a trunk has been ignored.

Your repository organization seems awkwardly restricted by the monthly cadence.  What if you need to do two code rolls in a month?  Do you create half month branches?

Your team is missing the concept of SVN tags.  Tags are finalized version not to be edited.  Those tags typically have version numbers like Application-1.2.3.  The version numbers are a triplet of integers: MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.  This indicates to developers how large the change in the application was, and how much one version differs from another.

Take a look at this online book, I have found it useful: 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.html